# Pytorch derivative calculation

Tags: math, pytorch, derivative

I have this simple pytorch code:

```
x = torch.arange(3,dtype=float)
x.requires_grad_(True)
y = 3*x + x.sum()
y.backward(torch.ones(3))
x.grad
```

This gives me [6,6,6], but shouldn't it be [4,4,4] ?
Because if we have f(x)=3 * x0 + 3 * x1 + 3 * x2 + x0+x1+x2, partial derivatives would be 3+1=4 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is correct, and here is why.

I will refer to the first element of your results, and you can extend to the other elements. You want to compute `dy1/dx1`, but this is not the correct way. The result your code computes is `dy1/dx1+ dy2/dx1 + dy3/dx1`.

The `ones` you pass in the `.backward` implies that the result computed would be `dot_product(ones, dy/dx)`. Note that `dy/dx` is a 3x3 matrix.

Comment: But dy1/dx1+ dy2/dx1 + dy3/dx1 is 4 ? Not 6

Comment: y1 = 4x1+x2+x3, y2=x1+4x2+x3, y3=x1+x2+4x3, so it should be 6.

Comment: But i have dy1/dx1=4, dy2/dx2=4 and dy3/dx3=4. All other derivatives are zero. I can't figure out how the 6 is computed

Comment: Why are other derivatives zero? if y1=4x1+x2+x3, then dy1/dx1=4, dy1/dx2=1, dy1/dx3=1.